# How to separate a small and capital characters together from a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider a string:- "HeLloWOrLD"

And now I have to separate characters like "H", "e", "LlL", "oO", "W", "r", "D" (they should be separated in such a manner that small and capital characters are in a same group).

So how can I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you'd like all letters, regardless of being lower-case or capital to be in the same group, then this will do. Time complexity of O(n):

```
d = {}
for char in "HeLloWOrLD":
    lower_char = char.lower()
    d[lower_char] = d[lower_char] + char if lower_char in d else char

>>> d.values()
dict_values(['H', 'e', 'LlL', 'oO', 'W', 'r', 'D'])
```

If instead you'd like all lower-case characters to be in the same group and all capital letters to be in the same group, then this is your solution:

Time complexity O(n):

```
str = "HeLloWOrLD"
str_lower = []
str_upper = []
for i in range(len(str)):
    if str[i].islower():
        if i != 0 and str[i-1].islower():
            str_lower[-1] = str_lower[-1] + str[i]
        else:
            str_lower.append(str[i])
    else:
        if i != 0 and str[i-1].isupper():
            str_upper[-1] = str_upper[-1] + str[i]
        else:
            str_upper.append(str[i])

>>> print(str_upper)
['H', 'L', 'WO', 'LD']
>>> print(str_lower)
['e', 'lo', 'r']
```

Comment: This is not OP's output

Comment: The question isn't very clear. He says the string is `"HeLloWOrLD"` but then he groups upper and lower case characters together, `"LlL", "oO"`.

The suggested solution groups the upper and lower case characters in the string in a single pass, as requested in the question: `separated in such a manner that small and capital characters are in a same group`

Comment: But all same letters like `L` and `l`

Comment: Sorry @DaniG2k for not mentioning a clear question. And thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use following solution:

```py
# split the sentence or word into tuples with leading lowercased value
# "He" -> [('h', 'H'), ('e', 'e')]
array_of_tuples = [(l.lower(), l) for l in list("HeLloWOrLD")]

# aggregate by lowercased value and collect real values into nested lists
result_dict = {}
for k, v in array_of_tuples:
    result_dict.setdefault(k, []).append(v)

# join the nested lists into strings
joined_result = ["".join(l) for l in result_dict.values()]

print(joined_result)
```